# android: mediaplayer.create() returns null

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

i try to let the user open an audio file and play this file. However, the `MediaPlayer.create()` method return `null`. Here is my code:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public void start(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,uri);
        //startThread();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

I tried it with mp3-files that my device has no problem playing with other players. the Uri i get looks like this `"content://media/external/audio/media/137650"`
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The create() API returns null if it somehow failed.
The reason in this case is due to a corrupt mp3 file. Have you tried different files?

Comment: Make sure that you have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. That, in turn, requires you to request runtime permissions, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher and you are testing on Android 6.0 or higher. You might also check LogCat for any relevant messages, as `MediaPlayer` has a tendency to log stuff at warning severity and not throw exceptions. Also, do not call `mediaPlayer.start()` in your `else` block, as you have not initialized `mediaPlayer`.

Comment: yes and as i said, other players can play those files. they are definetly not corrupt

Comment: feeling stupid now, i was certain had the permission... thanks

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me once the error was Unable to create media , It was the file that was causing the error file was .wav when i used .mp3 the error was gone

Comment: What dos this have to do with the question (OP is not having that error - they are getting a `null`!)

Comment: `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,uri);` This line was generating the error because of the file format that is in this case getting from uri. So after this line if you do `mediaPlayer.start()` THIS will generate null exception ... So what i meant is file format was the core issue behind this exception at least for my case

Comment: This section is for adding an answer to OP's question, not for describing issues with your code and how you fixed it!

Answer (score -2):

Try with following code :

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
```